# How to open facebook wall post in light box

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am able to post message with photo to my friends Facebook wall using my Facebook app.

Clicking on the post in Facebook wall should open light box with post details like photo and message.

How to open facebook post in light box in facebook.Is it possible?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at those possibilities: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

You could use the Send Dialog to send something to a friend. You don´t even need to authorize the user if you want to use those FB.ui Dialogs.

You can NOT use your own lightbox for that, Facebook luckily does not allow you to post to the wall of a friend with their API.